# Symfony 4, PHPUnit Bridge and phpunit location

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

If you install `phpunit/phpunit` package in Symfony **4** application, you get the message:

> Adding phpunit/phpunit as a dependency is discouraged in favor of Symfony's PHPUnit Bridge.
>
> - Instead:
>
>   1. Remove it now: `composer remove --dev phpunit/phpunit`
>   2. Use Symfony's bridge: `composer require --dev phpunit`

So, I installed `symfony/phpunit-bridge` package.
It created `bin/phpunit` file and `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`.

- If I run `bin/phpunit`, it downloads phpunit project and installs its dependencies in `bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5`.
- If I run `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`, it downloads phpunit project and installs its dependencies in `vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7`.

Note that the versions are not the same. Why?
And why to not use composer and its autoloader? Now we have troubles with it and other tools like PHPStorm (broken phpunit debugging, etc).
I know, that I can add phpunit path to main composer autoload, but this method seems very dirty.

How to use phpunit in Symfony 4 proper way, with all debugging integrations, etc?

Comment: its likely theyre using 5.7 and not 6.5 because of some BC breaks between the 2.  Why cant you point Storm at the simple-phpunit executable?

Comment: @DevDonkey how can it be done? I can't specify executable in `PHP:Test Framework` settings, only composer autoloader, phpunit.phar or global PEAR location.

Comment: point phpunit.phar to it.  It should be happy with that.

Comment: It looks like a dirty workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this issue by adding phpunit.xml.dist in the root of the Symfony.

The file existed previously but I suspect that when I did remove  phpunit, it also removed this file.. (I could be wrong but I am pretty certain)

When I add back the standard phpunit.xml.dist file to the root, it prompts me to add 'KERNEL_CLASS' variable in it.

When I add it in, it started working fine.

Full contents of my phpunit.xml.dist in case someone needs it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>src</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

<listeners>
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
</listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: First of all, I just want to say that the problem is fixed; you don't need to worry about deletion now. But generally, don't post comments (or new questions) as answers (like you did in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53431889/1)). These aren't actual answers, and are subject to deletion. Like I said though, it is an answer *now*, so you don't have to worry about it. Just saying it so you can avoid it in the future. You also have over 50 reputation, so you have enough rep to leave comments.

Comment: Yes, I created phpunit dist file. But the problem is I have to setup other tools: PHPStorm, phpstan, etc. They work with composer autoload, not custom autoload.